# English word for “fine under the circumstances”

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a single English word that means “fine, considering the circumstances”. I find I could use it a lot these days, in responding to people asking how I’m doing.

> I’m doing ___ (fineunderthecurcumstances).

Comment: Note that not many adverbs fit into the 'I'm doing ___' slot. //  'I'm prevailing' ... 'I'm flourishing' show extremes.

Comment: aswellascanbeexpected

Comment: **Why** do you need a single word for this? It doesn't take that much time or energy to say 'fine, considering the circumstances'.

Comment: That's what I have been doing.  I posted the original query because it does seem that there should be single word that has this connotation, but I'm coming around to thinking that at least in English there is no such single word.

Comment: [Asking "How are you?"](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/03/07/stop-asking-how-are-you-harvard-researchers-say-this-is-how-successful-people-make-small-talk.html) is generally done as an empty form of politeness, and usually isn't supposed to result in you answering in detail or truthfully. The polite response is something like "Very well, thank you. And yourself?"

Answer (score 2):

You could answer "I'm managing."

Answer (score 0):

> I’m doing ***OK/okay***.

Lexico:

> ***[OK](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ok)*** (also *okay*)
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>   *informal* predicative
>   **1** Satisfactory but not exceptionally or especially good.
>
> ‘In fairness, Casey probably did an okay job of the song, but I'd fallen asleep ten seconds into it.’
>
> **1.1** (of a person) in a satisfactory physical or mental state.
>
> ‘are you OK, Ben?’

Comment: OK does not do it for me.  I'm looking for something that connotes that one is actually doing WELL, considering the cirumstances, in a single word, or at least something better than fine under the cirumstances.  A friend kiddingly suggested the acronym "FUC".  or F.U.C., followed by initial for the word "kiddo".  I've come up with "Getting along", or "Hanging in there" but all have the same failing as OK in failing to convey that one is actually doing well, taking the situation into account.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a single word, but it's short: ***just fine.***

I particularly like this one because based on tone you can convey it different ways. A neutral tone would indicate managing well despite adverse circumstances. An emphatic tone would indicate managing exceptionally well. A slightly downtrodden tone would indicate being healthily well in a circumstance where someone could be underwater.

It's that it's so pliable but gives the definite sense that things are alright that makes me like it so much.

Comment: A good thought.  Doesn't work in an email.  I've had the issue come up both when responding to emailed questions about how I'm doing, and also in asking others, such as "I hope you're doing ______."  "fine" does not really work, nor "ok".

Comment: Context is important, I suppose. In that regard, your question might be incomplete. In any case where you'd be writing an email, and it's of the formal kind, I'd generally avoid greeting anyone with "I hope you're doing ___" and opting for a more formal greeting such as "I hope this finds you well"